# Color not rendering properly

Tags: java, colors

This stems from a problem that many people get from following vanZeben's game engine tutorial you can find [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8CAB66181A502179). The problem is a the rendering function vanZeben uses. It is very awkward and limiting. I need to remove it and replace it with code that renders the color that is on the sprite sheet.

Edit: [Here](https://github.com/vanZeben/2D-Game-Engine) is a link to the entire project's source.

The closest I've come is removing color >> from the int col initialization. It still removes all color, except for a tile that I added after I finished the tutorial.

```
//I know the problem comes from this section of code.               

int col = (color >> (sheet.pixels[xSheet + ySheet * sheet.width + tileOffset] * 8) & 255);

            if (col < 255)
            {
                for(int yScale = 0; yScale < scale; yScale++)
                {
                    if (yPixel + yScale < 0 || yPixel + yScale >= height) continue;

                    for(int xScale = 0; xScale < scale; xScale++)
                    {
                        if (xPixel + xScale < 0 || xPixel + xScale >= width) continue;
                        pixels[(xPixel + xScale) + (yPixel + yScale) * width] = col;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I just need col to equal the color of the pixel on the sprite sheet.